# ¿Como guardar un array en en mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

**Problema:**

tengo una base de datos de ejemplo en mongoDB que se debe verse exactamente así (él collection no existe hay que crearlo de este modo es solo un ejemplo):

```
{
"popularidad" : 0,
"nombre" : "lasaña",
"descripcion" : "lasaña rica",
"precio" : "12440",
"diaplato" : "Martes",
"ingredientes" : [ 
    {
        "proteinas" : [ 
            {
                "nombre" : "carne",
                "nombre" : "pollo"
            }
        ],
        "granos" : [ 
            {
                "nombre" : "pasta",
                "nombre" : "chile"
            }
        ],
        "otros" : [ 
            {
                "nombre" : "queso",
                "nombre" : "amor"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"adicional" : [ 
    {
        "nombre" : "mas carne",
        "precio" : "32000"
    }, 
    {
        "nombre" : "mas guevito",
        "precio" : "12000"
    }
],
"retirar_adicional" : [ 
    {
        "nombre" : "queso",
        "nombre" : "amor"
    }
],
"bebidas_var" : [ 
    {
        "nombre" : "limonada sin cubiertos",
        "precio" : "12000"
    }, 
    {
        "nombre" : "limonada con cubiertos",
        "precio" : "16000"
    }
],
"image" : [ 
    {
        "imgurl" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/loncheo1/image/upload/v1570587591/xtif3m13ch1n4pidkxee.png",
        "public_id" : "xtif3m13ch1n4pidkxee"
    }
],
"createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T02:19:51.895Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-10-09T02:19:51.895Z"),
"__v" : 0
}
```

Así que hice mi Schema de esta forma:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const IngredientesSchema = new Schema({
proteinas: { type: String, require: true },
granos: { type: String, require: true },
otros: { type: String, require: true }
});
module.exports = 
mongoose.model('IngredientesSchema',IngredientesSchema);

const AdicionalSchema = new Schema({
adicionales: { type: String, require: true },
adicionales_precio: { type: String, require: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('AdicionalSchema', 
AdicionalSchema);
const RetirarSchema = new Schema({
retirar: { type: String, require: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('RetirarSchema', RetirarSchema);
const BebidasSchema = new Schema({
bebidas: { type: String, require: true },
bebidas_precio: { type: String, require: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('BebidasSchema', BebidasSchema);
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
imgurl: { type: String, require: true },
public_id: { type: String, require: true }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('ImageSchema', ImageSchema);
const PlatosSchema = new Schema(
{
popularidad: { type: Number, require: true, default: 0 },
nombre: { type: String, require: true, unique: true },
descripcion: { type: String, require: true },
ingredientes: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 
'IngredientesSchema'}],
adicional: [AdicionalSchema],
retirar_adicional: [RetirarSchema],
bebidas_var: [BebidasSchema],
precio: { type: String, require: true },
diaplato: { type: String, require: true },
image: [ImageSchema]
},
{
timestamps: true
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Platos", PlatosSchema);
```

---

esto es lo que recibo para guardar en la db de un método post:

```
{
nombre: 'spagueti',
descripcion: 'spagueti a la boloñesa',
proteinas: [ 'carne', 'pollo' ],
granos: ['pasta', 'maíz'],
otros: ['salsa boloñesa','queso'],
dia: 'Miércoles',
precio: '33243',
adicionales: ['mas carne','mas pollo'],
adicionales_precio: ['12000', '23000'],
retirar: ['salsa boloñesa','queso'],
bebidas: ['limonada con cubiertos', 'limonada sin cubiertos'],
bebidas_precio: ['8000', '5000'],
}
```

---

hice un map para que me ponga todo en un objeto (solo con proteinas para pruebas):

```
      var proteinas_arr = new Array();
      proteinas.map((obj, index) => {
      proteinas_arr.push({
      nombre: obj,
      precio: moni[index]
      });
      });
      //y finalmente obtenemos el json
      var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(proteinas_arr);
      console.log("proteinas arr",proteinas_arr);
```

y mi método de guardado en mongoose es este personalmente creo que esta es la falla pero no se como solucionarla:

```
  var ingredientes = [{proteinas_arr, granos,  otros}];
  var adicional = [{adicionales, precioprueba}];
  var retirar_adicional = [{retirar}];
  var bebidas_var = [{bebidas,  precioprueba}];
  var image = [{imgurl, public_id}];

  const newPlatos = new Platos({ nombre, descripcion, precio, 
  diaplato, ingredientes, adicional, retirar_adicional, 
  bebidas_var, image });
```

no tengo mucha experiencia con mongoDB y estoy perdido asi que les agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

estoy usando express y handlebars para recibir los datos por el form (metodo POST).

modifique el parametro de proteinas en el schema por array pero sigue dando el mismo error:

```
(node:23949) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Platos 
validation failed: ingredientes: Cast to Array failed for value "[
{
proteinas_arr: [ [Object], [Object] ],
granos: 'asasa',
otros: 'sdsd'
}
]" at path "ingredientes"
```

Comment: ok lo corregiré

Comment: @MauricioContreras listo ya corregi

Comment: Pues hay varias cosas que definir mejor en tus esquemas. ¿El ejemplo de documento que colocas al inicio de tu pregunta es lo que estás buscando guardar en tu colección? La verdad no me queda claro el porqué guardarlo de esa forma. Otra cosa es que estás creando una colección para *ingredientes*, una colección para *adicionales*, ¿una colección para *retirar*?, una colección para *bebida* y otra para *imagen*. Suena a mucho de nada. ¿Exactamente qué deseas lograr? Parece que no tienes claro el tipo de documento que deseas guardar en tu DB. Sin saber eso es difícil darte una solución válida.

Comment: Me alegra que lo resolvieras, pero si has encontrado una solución, la misma debe ir en la sección de respuestas y no como lo pusiste en la misma pregunta. Por favor realiza los cambios necesarios. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** 
problema solucionado publico lo que hice para futuros usuarios con la misma duda:

```
    ingredientes:{ 
    proteinas: [{ type: Object, require: true}],
    granos: [{ type: Object, require: true}],
    otros: [{ type: Object, require: true}],
 },
```

el tipo de los elementos debe ser Object y se necesita un codigo para recorrer el array:

```
   var arr = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < proteinas.length; i++) {
      arr.push({
          nombre: proteinas[i],
          precio: moni[i]
      });
  }

  console.log("isi",arr)
```

y para guardarlo debes hacerlo así:

```
 const newPlatos = new Platos({ nombre, descripcion, precio, diaplato,  ingredientes: {proteinas: arr}});
```

Ojala les sea de ayuda :)